# Why Is XDocument.Descendants().Count() > 0 for an Empty Document?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Here's my method:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(source);
if (document.Descendants().Count() > 0)
{
    // Some code that shouldn't execute
}
else
{
    // Code that should execute
}
```

This code breaks when this is in the 'document' variable:

```
<ipb></ipb>
```

Since this DOESN'T have descendants, why is it entering the IF conditional? Is shouldn't try to load anything, yet it does and breaks when it finds nothing to scrape.

Using Breakpoints I can confirm that the document variable has the content I posted above when it breaks and it does enter the if.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using:

```
document.Root.Descendants().Count() > 0;
```

The Root element sits below the XDocument.

Comment: Also, consider using `document.Root.Descendants().Any()` to avoid counting all the descendants just to find out if there's at least one. (`XContainer.Descendants` uses deferred execution; i.e., is lazy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`ipb` is your first descendant on the document, right?  Don't you want `document.Root.Descendants()` ?

Comment: What do you mean 'inb'? You completely lost me. You ghost edited. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Sergio Boombastic:  Sorry.  I meant ipb.  Typo.  `<ipb></ipb>` is the first descendant of the document.  It is the root.  The document sits one level higher than the `ipb` node.  The behavior is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
if (docToValidate.Root.Descendants().Any())
{
   // has child elements.
{
else
{
   // does not have any child elements.
}
```

where 'docToValidate' is of type of XDocument.